# I think my SO question is on topic, would like it re-opened

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked a question on SO about a UI issue I am experiencing in Eclipse: [Eclipse Juno Editors side by side gives white bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745669/eclipse-juno-editors-side-by-side-gives-white-bar)

It was closed as "off topic" but I do not think it is off topic. The SO FAQ (https://stackoverflow.com/faq) covers questions asked about programming tools, which is what I am doing.

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers...
>   **software tools commonly used by programmers**
>   ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Further, I found the answer and would like to put it as an answer so that anyone else who experiences the same issue will know what to do. I added more detail to try and make it more useful.

Comment: It has now been reopened.

Comment: Now delete this post before a bunch of other meta users go in and re-close it!

Comment: Thanks for that. @Adam Rackis - should I really delete this question? My sarcasm meter may be broken atm... :)

Comment: @Robert - nah.  I was only half serious.  I think your question should be safe.

Comment: Wouldn't the more appropriate place for this be the eclipse bug tracker? Looks to me like it's at best going to solicit "me too" answers. If someone has a patch eclipse.org is the place to disseminate it.

Comment: From your answer, the question is "too localized"